# Erro de CORS XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: php, angularjs, cors

Estou com o seguinte problema:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Sempre que envio dados do `Angular` para o `PHP`.

Meu `PHP` está assim:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)

$name = $_POST['name'];
echo json_encode($name);
```

O angular tá certinho..

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.sendPost =  function (send) {
        $http.post('http://localhost/meuSite/www/server/sendemail.php', send).then(function success(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.data);
        }).then(function error(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

E coloquei um arquivo `.htaccess` na raiz com esse conteudo:

```
header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Por enquanto, está tudo *localhost*. O front eu to rodando com o http-server e o back com o `apache do xampp`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tá dificil saber aonde falhou, já que só tem alguns trechos de código.

Comment: Mas o código é basicamente esse. A principio só quero recuperar os dados enviados do angular no PHP. 
Eu testei só o angular e ta recebendo os dados, por isso não pus tudo, e no php só tem esse trecho, o resto eu retirei pra fazer esse teste e o codigo ficar + limpo. Vou colocar o angular inteiro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode ser do chrome e de localhost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin,https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/, https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/126 , https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: @Miguel pode ser, mas por não ter certeza melhor esperar o AP editar e detalhar. Ainda sim o link do github é uma otima dica.

Comment: Amigos, eu já alterei, coloquei o angular completo e ad uma foto com o erro tbm.

Comment: Já tentou colocar também no `.htaccess` a linha `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method"` ? O erro diz que o request header `Content-Type` não é permitido.

Comment: Felipe, mano, era isso :D 
o .htaccess ficou exatamente assim:
header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method"
Mt obgd cara, salvou meu dia!